# Array received from MongoDB aggregate function is not iterable

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Array received from MongoDB aggregate function is not iterable

```
[
  {
    _id: {
      type: 'checking-1912',
      carrier: 'Coyote',
      driver: 60c1ea82843e221784e5e8a1
    },
    total: 1390
  },
  {
    _id: {
      type: 'checking-1912',
      carrier: 'uber',
      driver: 60c1ea82843e221784e5e8a1
    },
    total: 5575
  },
  {
    _id: {
      type: 'checking-1912',
      carrier: 'Coyote',
      driver: 60c1dee27e641228589a7204
    },
    total: 1065
  },
  {
    _id: {
      type: 'checking-1912',
      carrier: 'uber',
      driver: 60c1dee27e641228589a7204
    },
    total: 2055
  },
  {
    _id: {
      type: 'receivable',
      carrier: 'Pinea',
      driver: 60c1dee27e641228589a7204
    },
    total: 1645
  },
  {
    _id: {
      type: 'checking-1912',
      carrier: 'Pinea',
      driver: 60c1ea82843e221784e5e8a1
    },
    total: 3665
  }
]
```

I am rendering it to my ejs template using below code. Please note I've assigned above result to totalIncome variable.

```
<% for(let income of totalIncome){ %>
  <p><%= income.total+=income.total %> </p>
<% }) %>
```

Why I am getting below error can anyone please help

> totalIncome is not iterable

Comment: I am able to see above array in console When I use console.log('totalIncome')

Comment: can you provide the code to perform the aggregation?

Comment: `<Key Name> is not iterable` error will occur if even one of the values is not an array. Make sure that all the values in `totalIncome` key are iterables.

Comment: here is aggregation code;

Comment: Dang `let totalIncome=Load.aggregate( [ { $group:{ _id:{"type":"$type","carrier":"$carrier" },"total":{$sum:"$credit" } } } ], function(err, result){
            if(err){console.log(err);}else{ return result;  } } )`